# variable assignment syntax in java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn Android development and java at the same time.

In this code:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    Button b =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
        }
     });
    }
```

Can someone explain the Button b =  ... line - is b an alias of Button, and why is the (Button) before findViewById?

Comment: People, please, do not downvote without leaving a reason why you downvoted this question.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses! Sorry is everyone feels it is a bad question, I did explain I am new to both java and android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at definition of `findViewById` method: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)
It returns `View` type, not Button.
But there are a lot of subclasses of `View` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Button, EditText, TextView etc...
So `(Button)` means that you cast general `View` type to required, which defined in XML layout.

Comment: So Button, EditText etc are, if I can say, variable types, just like INT or Array?

Comment: Every method in Java has return type, it can be: 
1) simple types - int, double;
2) class type - Button, View, Activity, some custom type;
3) arrays - int[], double[], Button[];
4) no return type - void;

Comment: There are primitives and objects in Java. int is a primitive, array is an object. Button, EditText, they are all objects, which essentially means they are instances of a class (basically).

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast this `View` as `Button` Widget and it's coming from your `activity_layout` with id `button1`.

```
Button b =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button b =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

`findViewById()` method returns a `View` which is superclass of Button. To use the View as a Button we need to typecast it. This is because some method of Button(subclass) may not be available in View(Superclass).

Answer (score 1):

It is called [TypeCasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Here `findViewById(R.id.btn_second)` is returning a View of type Button, so we to cast it to Button type.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_second);
```

Without the `(Button)`

`findViewById(R.id.btn_second)  will return a View.`

Android UI objects all derive from a type called `View` (docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)).

Answer (score 1):

b is variable of the type Button.

The (Button) means that the return-value of findViewById(...) is cast to a Button.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable type is written in front of assignment it is known as TypeCasting:

So in this case:

```
float floatVariable = 10.2;
int test = (int) floatVariable;
```

The float is cast to an int. This is necessary because an int variable cannot take a float unless it is explicitly cast.

In your case:

```
(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)
```

The method findViewById() returns a value that is then cast to a Button. This is necessary because that method does not return a Button.

Answer (score 1):

The method `findViewById` returns a View. With this code you are trying to find a Button given its id:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You need to do the cast to assign the result to a Button variable. If you did not cast the result to Button, you would not be able to call in b any method defined in class Button.